# Is it possible to create a DSN on a remote server in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dsn

I am trying to create a script such that I am given an array of server names and from these names I would like to create a system dsn on each of those respective machines.

I know that you can use SQLConfigDataSource() to create a dsn on your local machine, but it does not seem to give any parameters for creating the dsn on a separate machine.

Are there any functions that can achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [ps-exec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) for a task like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it, worst case you could just write the registry entries manually. To do that download [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), set it up to monitor registry changes and then create the DSN locally and you'll see what settings you need to change.

[Here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/11/10/can-i-create-and-delete-a-dsn-using-a-script.aspx)'s an article discussing that approach also (from a script perspective, but should be easy to do in C#).